# Create a Fortran extension module using F2PY with a custom signature file and subroutines stored in separate Fortran files?

Tags: python, numpy, f2py

As an exercise, I am trying to create a python module `fibadd1` which contains a single method `fibadd`. This method will eat an integer and spit out a numpy array of the first n fibonacci numbers with 1 added to them (i.e. 1, 2, 2, 3,...). The Fortran code containing this routine is `fib2.f`, and uses a subroutine `FIB` contained in `fib1.f`. This subroutine calculates the first N fibonacci numbers. With just these two files I have been able to successfully compile the given routine straight from the source, using a python script called `test2.py`. However, in trying to create a custom `.pyf` signature file as in [this tutorial](https://numpy.org/devdocs/f2py/f2py.getting-started.html), I have run into a road block. The signature file is called `fib2.pyf`.

I was able to successfully compile and run everything using the command `python -m numpy.f2py -c fib2.pyf fib2.f fib1.f --compiler=mingw32` from the command line. However, I would like to be able to use the `numpy.f2py.run_main(...)` and `numpy.f2py.compile(...)` functions to be able to do this in a python script. Based on [this documentation](https://numpy.org/devdocs/f2py/usage.html#python-module-numpy-f2py) it seems like they ought to have the same (or similar) functionalities. The script I tried is called `test3.py`.

It just gives a 1 on exit. Is it possible to do this in a python script? And also is there further documentation available than what I have linked? I have been having trouble parsing the `numpy.f2py.compile` function.

The source code is as follows:

`fib2.f`

```
C FILE: FIB2.F
      SUBROUTINE FIBADD(A,N)
C
C     ADD 1 TO THE FIBONACCI ROUTINE
C
      INTEGER N
      REAL*8 A(N)
      CALL FIB(A, N)
      DO I=1,N
          A(I) = A(I) + 1.0D0
      ENDDO
      END
C END FILE FIB2.F
```

`fib1.f`

```
C FILE: FIB1.F
      SUBROUTINE FIB(A,N)
C
C     CALCULATE FIRST N FIBONACCI NUMBERS
C
      INTEGER N
      REAL*8 A(N)
      DO I=1,N
         IF (I.EQ.1) THEN
            A(I) = 0.0D0
         ELSEIF (I.EQ.2) THEN
            A(I) = 1.0D0
         ELSE 
            A(I) = A(I-1) + A(I-2)
         ENDIF
      ENDDO
      RETURN
      END
C END FILE FIB1.F
```

`test2.py`

```
import numpy.f2py
import numpy as np

with open('fib2.f') as file:
    source = file.read()
module = 'fibadd1'
args = ['fib1.f', '--compiler=mingw32']
failure = numpy.f2py.compile(source, modulename=module, 
                             extra_args=args, verbose=False)
print(failure)

import fibadd1
a = np.zeros(8, 'd')
fibadd1.fibadd(a)
print(a)
```

`fib2.pyf`

```
!    -*- f90 -*-
! Note: the context of this file is case sensitive.

python module fib2
    interface
        subroutine fibadd(a,n)
            real*8 dimension(n),intent(out),depend(n) :: a
            integer intent(in) :: n
        end subroutine fibadd
    end interface 
end python module fib2

! This file was auto-generated with f2py (version:2).
! See http://cens.ioc.ee/projects/f2py2e/
```

`test3.py`

```
import numpy.f2py
import numpy as np

with open('fib2.f') as file:
    source = file.read()
module = 'fibadd1'
args = ['fib2.pyf','fib1.f', '--compiler=mingw32']
failure = numpy.f2py.compile(source, modulename=module, 
                             extra_args=args, verbose=False)
print(failure)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that, in the modified `.pyf` file there are two lines `python module fib2` and `end python module fib2` which dictate what the imported python module name will be (go figure). In order to successfully compile, the `modulename` keyword of the `numpy.f2py.compile` function must match that name. Thus, the corrected `.py` compilation script is:

```
import numpy.f2py

with open('fib2.f') as file:
    source = file.read()
    
module = 'fib2'
args = ['fib2.pyf','fib1.f', '--compiler=mingw32']

failure = numpy.f2py.compile(source, extra_args=args, 
                             modulename=module, verbose=False)
print(failure)

import fib2

a = fib2.fibadd(8)
print(a)
```